# Android and iOS user identification without registration

Tags: android, ios, in-app-billing

I want to develop an app for android and ios with in-app purchase capability. One of the "purchased virtual goods" I want to give to user (like a gift) only the first time.
I don't want implement user registration.
If the user reset own device and reinstall the app, I don't want to give him another gift.
What is the correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS - when uploading app if IAP contains, Apple ask for first time discount or also you can give promo code to user for this feature.[Refer to image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFDEo.png)